# css menu is not working in internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I have the following code form my menu.  It works in chrome and firefox but not in ie.  I dont know much about css and is trying to learn.  when i run my program in ie only the top menu appears and there is not submenus.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Administrator Page</title></head>
<style type="text/css" >
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 24px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
  -moz-border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  background: #8B8B8B;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#A9A9A9), to(#7A7A7A));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  border: solid 1px #6D6D6D;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #E7E5E5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
}
#menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-bar .active a, #menu-bar li:hover > a {
  background: #0399D4;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EBEBEB), to(#A1A1A1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a, #menu-bar li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#menu-bar ul a:hover {
  background: #0399D4 !important;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04ACEC), to(#0186BA)) !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CFCFCF));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px #B4B4B4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
}
#menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu-bar ul a {
  padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
  color:#424242 !important;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#menu-bar ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
}
#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
  html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}   
</style>
<div>
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Admin Pages</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="title_index.php">Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Matter Type</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Claims Hubs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Areas</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Firms</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="home.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>  

</table>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of IE you use?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php.

Comment: IE has not a good support for CSS ,especially CSS3 and the older the version you have,the worst will be the situation.Try using IE specific webkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have closed the HEAD tag twice (after TITLE and at the end of the STYLE).
And you don't have opened the BODY tag

Edit: try this code ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFGPc/))

```
<html>
<head><title>Administrator Page</title>
<style type="text/css" >
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 24px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
  -moz-border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  background: #8B8B8B;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#A9A9A9), to(#7A7A7A));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  border: solid 1px #6D6D6D;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #E7E5E5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
}
#menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-bar .active a, #menu-bar li:hover > a {
  background: #0399D4;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EBEBEB), to(#A1A1A1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a, #menu-bar li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#menu-bar ul a:hover {
  background: #0399D4 !important;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04ACEC), to(#0186BA)) !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CFCFCF));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px #B4B4B4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
}
#menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu-bar ul a {
  padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
  color:#424242 !important;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#menu-bar ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
}
#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
  html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}   
</style></head>
<body>
<div>
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Admin Pages</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="title_index.php">Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Matter Type</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Claims Hubs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Areas</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Firms</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="home.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Before posting problematic HTML on Stack Overflow, always run your code through the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) first. Invalid markup can dramatically affect the final rendered result.

Comment: @InsaneCoder When you don't conform to the W3 spec, the browser behavior is undocumented. Many incompatibility issues can be solved by writing valid code.

Comment: Exactly @LandonSchropp, the code posted is invalid: 2 head closure, no body tag and a table closure at the end without any opening tag. All we know that IE isn't so smart, so bad code creates bad pages

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you haven't closed the tags well.

Secondly,the different look is due to poor CSS support of IE.IE can really be a nightmare for web developers.

Check [CSS3 solutions for Internet Explorer](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 0):

@Max Markson is right, but there are more things to consider than just pointing out those errors. There is also a `</table>` tag there for no reason besides the fact that it's missing a body tag.

First of, here's a link to a [snippet of an HTML5 template](http://pragmaticode.com/snippets/basic-html5-template/). Once you get down the right template you can certainly add your `<style>` tags embedded in the document, but make sure you put the inside the `<head>` tag.

### The Fiddle

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sulfureous/T3XeK/)**

The Fiddle above shows the code in an easier testing environment.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify a Doctype, maybe it should solved it with IE10.
For older version, you must use [csshover.htc](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html) (very old solution)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Administrator Page</title></head>
<style type="text/css" >
#menu-bar {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 6px 6px 4px 6px;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 24px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 24px;
  -moz-border-radius: 24px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #666666;
  background: #8B8B8B;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#A9A9A9), to(#7A7A7A));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #A9A9A9,  #7A7A7A);
  border: solid 1px #6D6D6D;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
}
#menu-bar li {
  margin: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#menu-bar a {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #E7E5E5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 20px 6px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
}
#menu-bar li ul li a {
  margin: 0;
}
#menu-bar .active a, #menu-bar li:hover > a {
  background: #0399D4;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#EBEBEB), to(#A1A1A1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #EBEBEB,  #A1A1A1);
  color: #444444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:hover a, #menu-bar li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#menu-bar ul a:hover {
  background: #0399D4 !important;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04ACEC), to(#0186BA)) !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #04ACEC,  #0186BA) !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul {
  background: #DDDDDD;
  background: linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#CFCFCF));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #CFCFCF);
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 185px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34px;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 1px #B4B4B4;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #222222;
}
#menu-bar li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#menu-bar ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#menu-bar ul a {
  padding:10px 0px 10px 15px;
  color:#424242 !important;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #FFFFFF;
}
#menu-bar ul li:first-child > a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
}
#menu-bar ul li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
}
#menu-bar:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#menu-bar {
  display: inline-block;
}
  html[xmlns] #menu-bar {
  display: block;
}
* html #menu-bar {
  height: 1%;
}   
</style>
<div>
<ul id="menu-bar">
 <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Admin Pages</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="title_index.php">Title</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Matter Type</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Claims Hubs</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Areas</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Firms</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services Sub Menu 4</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="home.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>  

</table>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: I did the test with IE10, you code work well with the doctype.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in IE also. The only difference you found when compared with Firefox and chrome is different look and feel. Rounded corners and gradient backgrounds are not coming in IE because it doesn't have support for CSS3 features.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  With everyone's suggestions and advice especially  Max's i got it to work.  Thanks also for the referral to fiddle.  Will definitely use it in future.